# Deny login from certain hosts if logging in with specific sql credentials

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to stop some of our developers from connecting to the production sql server using a specific sql account. They have rights to connect through windows authentication with lower rights. They claim that changing the password will affect too many other processes running on our processing machine. So I want to deny access if they're connecting from there dev machines for now.

Another way this would work is if I could just allow connections from one specific host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a log on trigger that checks the ip/host before allowing connections

http://bluedog67.com/blog/post/SQL-Server-Logon-Trigger-Restricting-Access-By-IP-To-Your-SQL-Server-Instance.aspx